# при drag and drop bootstrap добавляет размытие - как его убрать?

Tags: bootstrap

при drag and drop bootstrap добавляет размытие - как его убрать?
[image: размытый елемент при перетаскиванмм]

Comment: Открыть стили и удбать размытие.

Comment: минимальный код, демонстрирующий проблему, в вопрос добавьте